# Determine to Assume Outer Diameter of Cable for Choosing Cable Gland

Tags: measurement, cables, wire

Is there any method to determine the cable outer diameter just only known from the pin connector which is M23 Connector 17 Pins?
I need the method for choosing cable gland size.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet or manufacturer's selection guide should give the cable's outer diameter. For a given number of conductors, the cable diameter can vary depending on insulation thickness and other construction details.

Many different-size cables could be used in any connector, regardless of the number of pins. The connector datasheet should describe the permissible range of cable sizes, and/or alternative cable glands or clamps available.

Comment: Actually, it's for sensor Vaisala PTB210 Barometric sensor, WMT700 Wind Sensor, Campbell Scientific cs700 Rain Gage, Campbell Scientific EE181 Temperature Sensor and Nova Lynx 255-100 Evaporation Gage, if you know any of these outer diameters of output cable, could you please inform me

Answer (score 0):

As Peter Bennett says, there's no substitute for looking at the manufacturer's datasheet for your type of cable.

For example, all of the following are 12-core cables made by Olex Australia:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So the answer to "What is the outside diameter of a 12-core cable made by Olex Australia?" is "Anything from 10.0mm to 24.2mm."

That said, glands are not particularly expensive, and each gland covers a range of outer diameters. So it would be reasonable to buy two or three different glands, and use the one that fits.

For example, one particular series of glands by CMP Australia has a selection table as follows:

[image]

So the "20", "25", and "32" size glands from this series would suffice for any cable size between 6.5mm and 26.3mm.

Comment: Actually, it's for sensor Vaisala PTB210 Barometric sensor, WMT700 Wind Sensor, Campbell Scientific cs700 Rain Gage, Campbell Scientific EE181 Temperature Sensor and Nova Lynx 255-100 Evaporation Gage, if you know any of these outer diameters of output cable, could you please inform me

Comment: @Hida, you are best off asking Vaisala, Campbell Scientific and Nova Lynx for the specifications of any cables that are included with their products. We could do the research for you, but we would not be any faster at it than you would be.

Comment: thank you for your input, I'll try to contact the manufacturer